# document.body.style.background = "red"; // Почему этот код работает?

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
document.body.style.background = "red";
```

Как-то никогда и не задумывался, а как это работает? Понятно, что это какая-то цепочка геттеров-сеттеров, но так сходу не смог объяснить. Немного пощупал...

```js
console.log( document.hasOwnProperty('body') ); // false
console.log( Object.keys(document) ); // ["location"]

console.log( document.constructor.name ); // HTMLDocument
// HTMLDocument.prototype.body;
// Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation — кажется это геттер.

Object.defineProperty(HTMLDocument.prototype, 'body', {
  get: () => "Mooo...",
});

console.log( document.body ); // "Mooo..." // Оно!
```

Дальше,

```js
console.log( document.body.hasOwnProperty('style') ); // false
console.log( document.body.constructor.name ); // HTMLBodyElement

// HTMLBodyElement.prototype.style // Illegal invocation
Object.defineProperty(HTMLBodyElement.prototype, 'style', {
  get: () => 100,
});

console.log( document.body.style ); // 100
```

```js
console.log( document.body.style.hasOwnProperty('background') ); // true
console.log( document.body.style.background ); // ""
```

Проблема в том, что пока писал вопрос, получился немного ответ)

Тогда, вопрос: Как реализовать объект `doc = {}`, который при выполнении

```
doc.body.style.background = "red";
```

примерно повторяя те же механизмы, (наследуя от классов-пустышек, похожих на `HTMLDocument`, `HTMLBodyElement`), изменит цвет body? Для присваивания `background = ...` использовать сеттер, выполняющий `document.body.style.background = ...`

Хотя осталось нераскрытым, что именно происходит за кулисами во время этого присваивания.

Comment: кто то минусанул - я плюсанул но кто то не сдержался

Comment: @MaximLensky Могу понять: Это какая-то хрень, которая в действительности нигде не нужна. Но почему-то именно такие вопросы возникают в 5 утра))

Comment: объекты `window`, `document`, `head`, `body` - это объекты которые создает браузер и связывает их с представлением документа в окне. У этих объектов нативная реализация. Свойства и методы этих объектов реализованы кодом браузера. Не совсем понятна суть вашего вопроса... Что означает слово "реализовать объект", который будет повторять ЧТО? Вы подразумеваете интерфейс объекта... или его поведение... или програмное создание представления документа... Вопрос плохой! Непонятный. Потому вас минусуют. Я не минусовал, если что... Опишите какую задачу вы хотите решить реализуя ваш объект `doc = {}`.

Comment: И еще... это не присваивание в широком смысле: `doc.body.style.background = "red";`. Прочитайте про геттеры и сеттеры в javascript. Возможно такие вопросы появляются от незнания програмного языка или спецификаций. В таком случае не проще ли один раз сесть и прочитать полный учебник по JS?

Comment: @NoSkill «"реализовать объект", который будет повторять ЧТО?» — Да, подразумевались интерфейсы объектов, чтобы нагляднее видеть, как они связаны, и какие вызовы происходят. get-set понимаю хорошо, вопрос появился случайно, когда попробовал в уме пошагово "прогнать", что происходит во время выполнения такой строчки, и не смог (незнание реализации document и прочего связанного с ним). Действительно, стоит лезть в спецификации и смотреть реализацию браузерных объектов, спасибо)